# background image won't stay behind all content

Tags: html, css

I can't find a way to get a everything in front of the image even when I use 
z-index: -100; the content does not go over the image

Comment: How about putting some code in your question?

Comment: Have you tried to make it a css backgrund image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Firstly:

Put a `<div>` container around the `section` you need a background image. Add a class to the `<div>`

#### Secondly:

```
.divContainerClass{ background-image(url:images/img.jpg); }
```

It will now be in the background of everything